# making modals, using ReactDOM.createPortal() - Target container is not a DOM element Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I want to make a modal in react, but I can't put my modal in the index.html or index.jsx,

why?

because I was given an existing code to work with, it will be so much easier to just go with the existing code, rather than make it from scratch.

here is my modal :

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function Modal({ children, modalRef}) {
  const component = <div className="modal">{children}</div>;

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, {});
  });

  // {this.props.modalRef.current?(ReactDom.createPortal(<...Modal>, this.props.modalRef.current):null}

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(component, document.querySelector("#modal"));
}

export default Modal;
```

as you can see I have tried to use the older StackOverflow's answer, but I don't know how to make it works

here is one of the children

```
{createRest && (
        <Modal  >
          <CreateRestaurant close={() => setCreateRest(false)} />
        </Modal>
      )}

      {user && (
        <Modal  >
          <UserSidebar close={() => setUser(false)} />
        </Modal>
      )}

      {rest && (
        <Modal  >
          <RestaurantSidebar
            close={() => setRest(false)}
            create={() => {
              setCreateRest(true);
              setRest(false);
            }}
          />
        </Modal>
      )}
```

### Edit

Turns Out I can actually manually create div with class and id for modal in Index.js

```
      <div className="modal" id="modal"></div>
```

but it doesn't show anything, in the inspect it is there, but it doesn't show anything even if I change the height or the width, z index, etc.

here is the image inspection :

[image]